# MOSFET Gate Resistor Problem in CHG, DSG pins

Tags: mosfet, resistors, bms, rise-time

I am trying to design a BMS circuit by using [BQ77915](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq77915.pdf?ts=1673344457991&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ77915) . My charge and discharge mosfets are [CSD18534KCS](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18534kcs.pdf?ts=1673344167437&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). They are only using for switching. The problem is BQ77915 datasheet says for gate resistors of CHG/DSG FETs that "System designers should adjust this parameter to meet the desirable FET rise/fall time." CHG and DSG pins output voltage is typical 12 Volts, its maximum output current is 1 mA.

So, if I want the rise time as 1 milisecond in CHG and DSG FETs; how should I choose the gate resistor value?

In my opinion; the charge that I have to give is, **Q=CV** where Ciss is 1500pF on mosfet datasheet and V=12 V from BQ77915. So, Q=18 nC. And, **Q=Igate** times **ton**(1ms) then, Igate is 18 mikroAmper. Rgate=83K ohm from V/Igate. Do you think I am right? Or what is the idea of this adjusting?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What current are the MOSFETs controlling. Bigger current for the same rise time requires a lower value of resistor. You might serve yourself better if you simulated your charge/discharge circuit.

Comment: Mosfets are controlling up to 8A. Thank you, I will try to simulate. @Andy aka